# Execution failed for task app:dexDebug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, material-design

this my gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "done.ui"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
        maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.5'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kanytu:android-parallax-recyclerview:v1.4'
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.8.5.jar')
}
```

message gradle build after run project
this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: it might help to post more of your error - that is the gradle process exception. It is telling you that there was an error in the java process that it was running - so there is another error before this one.

Comment: use ./gradlew assemble --info and post the stacktrace

Comment: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

i want to make this command how?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti how Run this command
 --stacktrace option to get the stack trace or  --info and post the stacktrace

Comment: you can use in the terminal in the root project the command ./gradlew assembre --info

Answer (score 0):

Try this

You use `buildToolsVersion` 22  and your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` is 21

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "done.ui"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
        maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.5'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kanytu:android-parallax-recyclerview:v1.4'
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.8.5.jar')
}
```

Comment: Update build tools to 23.0.2 and sdk to 23

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
//compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])//<==Just comment this line
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.2.0'
compile 'com.pubnub:pubnub-android:3.7.4'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.+'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb-mapper:2.+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.5.5'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.github.kanytu:android-parallax-recyclerview:v1.4'
compile files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.8.5.jar')
}
```

comment this line and re-build again that's it `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`

and don't forget to add this

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Use **--debug** option to get more detailed output. 
   It is possible that you have dependencies conflict and dex trying to process same class file from different libraries and failing. If this is the case you should filter out libraries you don't need.

use:

```
compile ("alibpath") {
   transitive = false
}
```

to skip transitive libraries.

2. The other possibility is that you have java.* javax.* classes in your libs, dex doesn't like it.